# serial number with pagination rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I am using pagination for my index page where I list all the users information like name, email etc. In the table I want to display the serial number in the order [1,2,3...]. If I user the user_id and if I delete the user the number will be missing out of sequence. I use the following code in my view

```
 <% @user.each_with_index do |d, i| %>

 <tr>

    <td><%= i+1 %></td>
    <% if d.profile.present? %>
   <td><%= link_to d.profile.first_name+ " "+d.profile.last_name, posts_individualpostlink_path(:id => d.id) %> </td>
   <% else %>
    <td><%= "No Profile" %></td>
    <% end %>       
   <td><%= d.email %></td>
   <% if d.profile.present? %>
   <td><%= d.profile.date_of_birth %> </td>
   <% else %>
    <td><%= "No Profile" %></td>
    <% end %>

  </tr>
<% end %>

</table>
 <%= will_paginate @user %>
```

when I am going to the second page again the serial number starts with [1,2,....]. Per Page if i am giving 10 users, the second page should show [11, 12, 13,..... in the table.

Can anyone help me to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with

```
<% 
count = ((params[:page] || 1).to_i - 1) * 10
@user.each_with_index do |d, i| %>

 <tr>

    <td><%= count + i %></td>
```

Comment: If i do so I am getting the first number in the series as 10 and the second page starting number as 20. But the first number should be 1.

Comment: Yeah..yes u need to do -1 to params[:page]. Please check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Before answering question, small emotional note: stop using single letter variables in Your code. It makes it completely unreadable.
Why not use `<% @user.each_with_index do |user, idx| %>` ? Now in You code block it's easy to understand that You always refer to user.

Now the answer. Will paginate add page parameter to the paging links. So in You controller You should be able to do this:

```
@page = params[:page] || 1
```

After that use it to calculate correct number in Your view:

```
<td><%= (@page - 1) * number_of_items_on_page + i+1 %></td>
```

Comment: '<td><%= (@page.to_i - 1) * number_of_items_on_page + i+1 %></td>' worked. Thanks for your suggestion on single letter variable. I will make a practice of using readable code.

Comment: Isn't there some method or option provided by will_paginate gem?